# Creating JSON array of arrays with keys from MySQL into sing JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array, key

I am trying to create an array of arrays in a loop to a JSON object, but It returns two objects instead. If I remove the array around the array with a key, it works but I need the key.

This is the format I am looking for:

```
$shop = array( "1408842145690" => array( id => "1408842145690", 
                                 code => "1",
                                 title => "zdfdsf",
                                 date => "2014-08-01",
                                 description => "fghgf"
                                ),
        "1408840099517" => array( id => "1408840099517", 
                                 code => "1",
                                 title => "test",
                                 date => "2014-08-01",
                                 description => "this is a test"
                                )
         );echo json_encode($shop);
```

This is the code I am using

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM todolist ";
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tasks = array(
                       $row['task_id'] => array( 'id' => $row['task_id'],
                                           'code' => $row['task_statusbox'],
                                           'title' => $row['task_title'],
                                           'date' => $row['task_date'],
                                           'description' => $row['task_description']
                                          )             
                    );  
        $alltasks[] = $tasks;
    }
    echo json_encode($alltasks);
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();  
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
{"1408842145690":{"id":"1408842145690","code":"1","title":"zdfdsf","date":"2014-08-01 00:00:00","description":"fghgf"}},{"1408840099517":{"id":"1408840099517","code":"1","title":"test","date":"2014-08-01 00:00:00","description":"this is a test"}}
```

This is the result I am looking for

```
{"1408842145690":{"id":"1408842145690","code":"1","title":"zdfdsf","date":"2014-08-01","description":"fghgf"},"1408840099517":{"id":"1408840099517","code":"1","title":"test","date":"2014-08-01","description":"this is a test"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the contents of your while loop with the following:

```
$tasks = array('id' => $row['task_id'],
             'code' => $row['task_statusbox'],
             'title' => $row['task_title'],
             'date' => $row['task_date'],
             'description' => $row['task_description']
         );            
$alltasks[$row['task_id']] = $tasks;
```

EDIT: I tested the above, and it does work. Here is the full code with the replacement intact... try a copy/paste.

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM todolist ";
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tasks = array('id' => $row['task_id'],
            'code' => $row['task_statusbox'],
            'title' => $row['task_title'],
            'date' => $row['task_date'],
            'description' => $row['task_description']
        );            
        $alltasks[$row['task_id']] = $tasks;
    }
    echo json_encode($alltasks);
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();  
}
```

Comment: That is giving me brackets around my array and isnt working.{"1408842145690":[{"id":"1408842145690","username":"seanflores86","code":"1","title":"zdfdsf","date":"2014-08-01 00:00:00","description":"fghgf"}],"1408840099517":[{"id":"1408840099517","username":"seanflores86","code":"1","title":"test","date":"2014-08-01 00:00:00","description":"this is a test"}]}

Comment: Sounds like you left an extra array(...) tag in there.

Comment: would you please elaborate on how to fix it?

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, howabout marking it as the correct answer?